# Spherical Camera in Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Are there any plans to add a spherical camera in Eevee? As a content creator for planetarium theaters there are certain instances where having the ability to set the camera output to panoramic-equirectangular in Eevee would be great. In order to speed up render times I often render elements and then later composite them into a scene that looks like it was a fluid single render scene. Eevee is much faster when there isn't a need for raytracing.

Is this even possible?

Thanks,

Troy

Comment: Not quite sure if it would help you at all, but there is an Eevee VR addon here: https://github.com/EternalTrail/eeVR

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. We don't determine development priorities nor what features will be included or not. If you can rephrase your quest to focus on the issue, rather than ask if it will be implemented, please edit it so we can reopen.